# Depth First Search Parent, Distance, Finish Java problem

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am having issues with my DFS. So, I believe my actual depth-first search is working, but **my parent node (pi), distance (d), and finish (f) gives back some wonky numbers.**

I have been following the pseudo code very closely, putting the variables exactly as they are in the DFS example in the book.

[image]

My strategy is to pass in 4 ArrayLists: vertex (current vertex), pi (parent), d (distance), f (finish) of size of the number of total vertices into the DFS function and add values as they occur in the recursion.

DFS

```
    enum VertexState {
White, Gray, Black}

// The function to do DFS traversal. It uses recursive DFSVisit()
//passes in 4 array lists (vertex, pi, d, f) that keep track of current vertex, parent node, distance, and finish times respectively
public void DFS(List<Integer> vertex, List<Integer> pi, List<Integer> d, List<Integer> f)
{
    VertexState state[] = new VertexState[numberOfVertices()];

    // Mark all the vertices as white (not visited)
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices(); i++) {
        state[i] = VertexState.White;
    }

    int time = 0; //initialize time

    // Call the recursive helper function to print DFS traversal
    // starting from all vertices one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices(); i++) {
        if( state[i]== VertexState.White)
        DFSVisit(i, state, vertex, pi, d, f, time);
    }
}


// A function used by DFS
//passes in u (current node) and it's state (color)
//passes in 4 array lists (vertex, pi, d, f) that keep track of current vertex, parent node, distance, and finish times respectively
public void DFSVisit(int u, VertexState[] state, List<Integer> vertex, List<Integer>pi, List<Integer>d, List<Integer>f, int time)
{
    time=time+1; //increment time (white vertex u has been discovered)
    d.add(time); //add current time int to distance array list

    // Mark the current node as gray (visited)
    state[u] = VertexState.Gray;

    vertex.add(u); //add current node to vertex array list

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    Iterator<Integer> i = adjacencies[u].listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        int n = i.next();
        if (state[n]==VertexState.White)
        {
            pi.add(n); //add current node to parent array list
            DFSVisit(n, state, vertex, pi, d, f, time);
        }
    }
    state[u] = VertexState.Black; //mark current node as black (it is finished)
    time=time+1; //increment time
    f.add(time); //add current time int to f (finished) array list
}
}
```

Driver

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //GENERATED GRAPHS
    Graph g = new Graph(10, 0.3);
    System.out.println("The graph is");
    System.out.println( g.toString());
    System.out.println("It had " + g.numberOfVertices() + " vertices and " + g.numberOfEdges() + " edges.");

    //initialize array lists to print
    List<Integer> vertex = new ArrayList<Integer>(g.numberOfVertices());
    List<Integer> pi = new ArrayList<Integer>(g.numberOfVertices());
    List<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>(g.numberOfVertices());
    List<Integer> f = new ArrayList<Integer>(g.numberOfVertices());

    //depth first search
    g.DFS(vertex,pi,d,f);

    //print array lists
    System.out.println("Vertex:   "+vertex);
    System.out.println("Parent:   "+pi);
    System.out.println("Distance: "+d);
    System.out.println("Finish:   "+f);

}
}
```

**The output looks like:**

The graph is

0: [1, 5, 7]

1: [2, 6, 8, 9]

2: [1, 3, 4]

3: [0, 1, 2, 8]

4: [1, 4]

5: [0, 4, 6]

6: [2, 6, 8]

7: [0, 8]

8: [5]

9: [3, 8]

It had 10 vertices and 27 edges.

Vertex:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 4, 6, 9, 7]

Parent:   [1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 4, 6, 9, 7]

Distance: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 3, 2]

Finish:   [8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should print which values you expect.

I did not examine the entire code, but f will definitely hold wrong values.

1. The order of the lists d and f is inverse.
2. The value will always be d + 1 since the value will not "come out" increased from the recursive call.

So the following advice to overcome those bugs. Do not mix lists and arrays since your access is "broken". Stick to arrays in your case. Or, much better, make a real attribute object "owned" by each vertex, like (pseudo-code)

```
public class VertexAttribute {
  VertexState state;
  Object parent;
  int distance;
  int finished
}
```

And than pass the list of those attributes to your "helper" method and you never will mix attributes of different vertices.